# How to drop an empty level in a multiindex dataframe

Tags: pandas, multi-index

I have a df that looks like this:

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex(levels=[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']],labels=[[2, 3, 0, 1]])
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(4)}, index=mux)
```

How can I drop the empty level to form a single-index df? I have tried

```
pd.MultiIndex.droplevel(df, level=0)
```

But got the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'levels'
```

Where did I get wrong?

I have also tried the following, but the index matching for some reason gets messed up (eg. the original row for 'A' is matched with 'B'), even it I use `sort_index`.

```
df.index=df.index.levels[0]
```

Comment: sort_index(inplace=True) worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) with assign back or with [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) because it is special type of `MultiIndex` with only one level:

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex(levels=[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']],
       labels=[[2, 3, 0, 1]])

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':range(4)}, index=mux)
print (df)
   a
C  0
D  1
A  2
B  3

df.index = df.index.get_level_values(0)
print (df.index )
Index(['C', 'D', 'A', 'B'], dtype='object')

print (df)
   a
C  0
D  1
A  2
B  3
```

Or:

```
df = df.set_index(df.index.get_level_values(0))
print (df.index)
Index(['C', 'D', 'A', 'B'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: I tried and got the error: ValueError: Must pass non-zero number of levels/labels

Comment: @edge27 - So problem with real data? In sample for me it working nice. I add output of `df` before and after. Or need something different?

Comment: Sorry I thought `level[0]` is equal to `get_level_values(0)`, but apparently the latter takes care of the matching. So yes, it worked. Or if I use `level[0]`, I need to `sort_index` first. The problem was I forgot `inplace=True`.

Comment: @edge27 - No problem, nice day!